# How to extract the value of a variable outside Nodejs callback function

Tags: node.js, variables, callback, scope, request

I am unable to get the value of the response outside the callback code. It returns undefined outside whereas in the callback it is giving proper result.

```
function doCall(urlString, callback) {
    request.get(
        urlString,
        null,
        null,
        (err, data, result) => {                              
            var statusCode = result.statusCode;
            return callback(data);
        }
    );
}

const apiResponse = doCall(urlString, function(response) {
    console.log('***************************' + response); //Prints correct result
    return JSON.parse(response);
});

console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++++++' + apiResponse); //Prints undefined
```

Comment: You will need to use a promise or async/await

Comment: Your function `doCall` does not return anything, so affecting its return "value" to `apiResponse` sets its value to `undefined`.

Comment: but doCall is returning 'return callback(data)'. but is that not correct?

Comment: @Jeff how will using async help me get a value outside of the function.

Comment: You need to read up on how the event loop and async works in node. You need to setup something like var response = await getResponse() from a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function doCall(urlString) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(
            urlString,
            null,
            null,
            (err, data, result) => {
                if (error) reject(error);
                var statusCode = result.statusCode;
                resolve(data);
            });
    });
}

async function myBackEndLogic() {
    try {
        const result = await doCall(urlString);
        console.log(result);
       //return JSON.parse(result) if you want

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('ERROR:');
        console.error(error);
    }
}

myBackEndLogic();
```

[Read this for more explanations](https://javascript.info/async)

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this. I was able to run the code.

Comment: Welcome. Read the link i provided. It will help to clear lots of confusions in nodejs.

Comment: I would also highly recommend this course on Udemy (https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-nodejs-developer-course-2/). Even if you have a pretty good background in programming it covers a lot of things that are unique/different with nodejs.

Comment: Thank you Jese and Jeff. The links are very useful. I am very grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want synchronous looking code, wrap everything in an async function:

```
(async (){
    async function doCall(urlString, callback) {
        return await request.get(urlString, null, null); // or store in a variable and return modified response
    }
    const apiResponse= await doCall(urlString, (response) => {
        console.log('response', response);
        return JSON.parse(response);
    });
    console.log('apiResponse', apiResponse);
})()
```